# Why does simple UDF throw an unsupported error?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

just using UDF function to concat 2 strings ..The following is my code

```
import  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val udfconcat =udf[String ,String, String](concat_udf)

spark.sqlContext.udf.register("udf_sel","udfconcat")

spark.sql("select FirstName,LastName, udf_sel(FirstName,LastName) AS CONCATENATEDNAME FROM checks").show()

def concat_udf(fN: String,lN : String) : String ={
    fN + lN
}
```

My Schema is

```
   EmployeeID|      int|   null|
|   FirstName|   string|   null|
|    LastName|   string|   null|
|DepartmentID|   bigint|   null|
|      Salary|   double|   null|
```

When I try to execute I am getting

> Schema for type Char is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing **`String,String`** while registering udf but to register UDF we need to pass args as **`String`,`function`**

- for this case we need to pass **`"udf_sel",concat_udf _`**

**Try with any of these approaches:**

```
def concat_udf(fN: String,lN : String) : String ={
    fN + lN
}

spark.sqlContext.udf.register("udf_sel",concat_udf _)

spark.sql("select FirstName,LastName, udf_sel(FirstName,LastName) AS CONCATENATEDNAME FROM checks").show()
```

(or)

```
val cnct=(fn:String,ln:String)=> {fn + ln}

spark.sqlContext.udf.register("udf_sel",cnct)

spark.sql("select FirstName,LastName, udf_sel(FirstName,LastName) AS CONCATENATEDNAME FROM checks").show()
```

(or)

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("udf_sel",(fn:String,ln:String) => fn+ln)

spark.sql("select FirstName,LastName, udf_sel(FirstName,LastName) AS CONCATENATEDNAME FROM checks").show()
```

Comment: Ur 3rd option worked for me fine..,Though I did not check 1st and 2nd option..Thanks a lot @Shu